# How to use ngModel to bind an input control with Javascript after AngularJS's bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

How to use ngModel to bind an input control with JavaScript after AngularJS's bootstrap?

I tried to add `ng-model` attribute by `setAttribute` method, but it didn't work!

```
    function FormController($scope) {
        $scope.name="OK";

        $scope.createBind=function(){
                    var texteditor=document.getElementById("test");
                    if(texteditor.getAttribute("ng-model")==null){
                        texteditor.setAttribute("ng-model","name");
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                }
    }

<input type="text" id="test">
<button ng-click="createBind()">Bind</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular don't get changes if you make them via javascript or jquery or etc...

You should call `$scope.$apply()` to get such changes manually...

Here is a good [**article**](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) for you to understand `$scope.apply()`...

Comment: I tried to call $scope.$apply() after input.setAttribute("ng-model","xx"),but it didn't work!

Comment: no,Maybe I should read the AngularJS source code first to solve this question!

Comment: @user3431353 can you post your code or create plunker?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function FormController($scope) {
            $scope.name="OK";
    
            $scope.createBind=function(){
         var texteditor=document.getElementById("test");
         if(texteditor.getAttribute("ng-model")==null){
          texteditor.setAttribute("ng-model","name");
          $scope.$apply();
         }
        }
        }
    </script>

Comment: <body ng-controller="FormController">
    <input type="text" id="test">
    <button ng-click="createBind()">Bind</button>
  </body>